# How can I do the following using Java 8 Lambdas

Tags: java, lambda

I have a set of Strings as follows

```
Set<String> ids;
```

Each id is of the form `#userId:#sessionId` so for e.g. `1:2` where 1 is the userId and 2 is the sessionId.

I want to split these into userId which would be the key in a HashMap and each userId is unique. But each userId can have multiple sessions. So how do I get the values from `Set<String>` to `Map<String, List<String>>`

For e.g.

If the set contains the following values `{1:2, 2:2, 1:3}` 
The map should contain

```
key=1 value=<2,3>
key=2 value=<2>
```

Comment: Sorry to be the "What have you tried?" guy, but have you thought about the problem at all?  You'll probably get someone to write the code either way, but you're more likely to _learn_ if you tell us what you tried and what you don't understand.

Comment: Do you actually have `#` in front of your values?

Answer (score 0):

By "lambdas" I'm assuming you mean streams, because a straightforward loop to build a map wouldn't really require lambdas. If so, you can get close, but not quite there, with some of the built-in `Collectors`.

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = ids.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(id -> id.split(":")[0]));

// result: {"1": ["1:2", "1:3"], "2": ["2:2"]}
```

This will group by the left number, but will store the full strings in the map values rather than just the right-hand portion.

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = ids.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        id -> id.split(":")[0],
        id -> new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(id.split(":")[1])),
        (l1, l2) -> {
            List<String> l3 = new ArrayList<>(l1);
            l3.addAll(l2);
            return l3;
        }
    );

// result: {"1": ["2", "3"], "2": ["2"]}
```

This will return exactly what you want, but suffers from severe inefficiency. Rather than adding all equal elements to a single list, it will create many temporary lists and join them together. That turns what should be an O(n) operation into an O(n<sup>2</sup>) one.

Comment: I'm surprised you have an output because `new ArrayList<>(id.split(":")[1])` should not compile. I guess you meant `id -> Arrays.asList(id.split(":")[1])`. But this is were the downstream collectors features is useful (speaking about your first attempt): `.collect(groupingBy(id -> id.split(":")[0], mapping(id -> id.split(":")[1], toList())));` gives the expected result. Note that you could do a map with split before calling collect to be more efficient by avoiding two split calls on the String...

Comment: ... so that it reduces to: `.stream().map(id -> id.split(":")).collect(groupingBy(id -> id[0], mapping(id -> id[1], toList())));`

Answer (score -1):

You could use `HashMap<Integer,Set<T>>` or `HashMap<Integer,List<T>>`, where T is the type of value1, value2, etc..

I think you're asking for something [similar to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7351083/how-to-store-several-values-to-one-key-java).

Also, here is a link for several solutions on [how to proceed with this problem](http://java.dzone.com/articles/hashmap-%E2%80%93-single-key-and).